# Как из input-а передать значение в controller и по этому значению сделать выборку из БД (Без перезагрузки )

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, opencart

Нужно вывести товары, у которых аналогичные размеры (длина, ширина, высота) с допустимой погрешностью +-2мм.

в файле `catalog/view/theme/defaultresponsive/template/product/product.tpl`
у меня есть блок *.productAnalog*, в нем отображаются нужные мне товары.

на этой же странице у меня есть input, в который клиент может ввести интересующий размер, и есть скрипт:

Html:

```
<input type="text" size="5" name="option[242]" value="<?php echo $option['option_value']; ?>" />
```

Js:

```
        $('input[name=\'option[242]\']').bind('keyup', function() {


    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=product/product/analogFilters',
        type: 'post',
        //dataType: 'json',
        data: 'size_a=' + encodeURIComponent($('input[name=\'option[242]\']').val()),
        success: function(data){ 

            $('.productAnalog').load('.../index.php?route=product/product&product_id=2419 .productAnalog');

        }
    });

});
```

в /catalog/controller/product/product

у меня есть метод:

```
public function analogFilters() {
    $this->load->model('catalog/product');
    $this->model_catalog_product->getProductAnalog($this->request->post);
}
```

В `/catalog/model/catalog/product`
есть функция:

```
public function getProductAnalog($data) {


    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT *, pd.name AS name FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "product p LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "product_description pd ON (p.product_id = pd.product_id) WHERE (length BETWEEN '".($data['size_a']-2)."' AND '".($data['size_a']+2)."' ) AND (width BETWEEN '".($data['size_b']-2)."' AND '".($data['size_b']+2)."' )");


    $product_data = array();
    foreach ($query->rows as $result) { 
        $product_data[$result['product_id']] = $this->getProduct($result['product_id']);
    }

    return $product_data;
}
```

`/catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/product.tpl`
блок с выводом результата:

```
    <div class="productAnalog">
    <p><b>Фильтры в наличии с аналогичными параметрами:</b></p>
    <?php if ($productsAnalog) { ?>
      <?php foreach ($productsAnalog as $product) { ?>
            <div class="name"><a href="<?php echo $product['href']; ?>"><?php echo round($product['length'] *100)/100; ?> * <?php echo round($product['width'] * 100)/100; ?></a> - </div>
            <?php if ($product['price']) { ?>
            <div class="price">
              <?php if (!$product['special']) { ?>
              <?php echo $product['price']; ?>
              <?php } else { ?>
              <span class="price-old"><?php echo $product['price']; ?></span> <span class="price-new"><?php echo $product['special']; ?></span>
              <?php } ?>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
      <?php } ?>
     <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Сейчас у меня все работает так, как надо, только, если я в controllere или modele вручную укажу значения, например: `$data['size_a'] = 258;` Мне же нужно, чтобы в `$data['size_a']` записывались значения из `input`, в который клиент вводит свои размеры и при каждом нажатии цифры вызывалась функция `select` и результат отображался в блоке `.productAnalog`.

Теперь, если коротко: мне как-то нужно добавить значение из `input` в переменную и по ней сделать выборку товаров и отобразить результат на странице, без перезагрузке.

Пожалуйста, помогите решить эту задачу, я уже с ума схожу... подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так, что нужно сделать или что я не сделал?

Comment: `html` еще свой покажите пожалуйста

Comment: Не наблюдаю никаких инпутов, на которые должен распространяться код

Comment: Добавил input вначале скрипта в верхней части вопроса

Comment: Никто не может помочь? Кажется должно быть что-то по принципу живого поиска

Comment: А возвращать не `json_encode($product_data)` надо?